# Using svychisq with subset -- error "object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, survey

I'm trying to find the adjusted-chi square p-value of the differences in prevalence of the ordinal variable (with 4 levels), `y_4`, in the dataset as a surveydesign, `svydes`, made from the dataset, `ds`, using a subset of the three-valued categorical variable, `x_3`. I'm interested in the p-value of prevalence of the different levels of `y_4`, in the subset of respondents that have x_3 == 1. I've tried

```
library(survey)
y_4 = sample(0:3,100, TRUE)
x_3 = sample(1:3, 100, TRUE)
finalwt = runif(n = 100,min = 0, max = 1)
ds = as.data.frame(cbind(y_4,x_3,finalwt))
svydes = svydesign(ids = ~0, weights = ~finalwt, data = ds)
x1 = subset(svydes,x_3 == 1)
svychisq(~y_4 , x1, statistic ="F",na.rm = TRUE)
```

I get the following error: "Error in formula[[2]][[2]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable".
Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?

Similarly, trying some similar with the `survey` package, the following gives the same error:

```
summary(svytable(~y_4,x1),statistic = "F")
```

I've tried to make a reproducible example, however my actual survey sample has clusters and strata, so I'm not sure how to reproduce that in my example.  Suggestions welcome!  The actual surveydesign code looks like the following:

```
svydes= svydesign(id =~`_PSU`,strata =~ `_STSTR`, weights =~finalwt, data = ds, nest = TRUE )
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You can simulate data that looks like yours or share a `dput()` of your data. But since we don't know what it looks like at all at this point it's hard to say the best way to make it reproducible.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you!  I've tried to add a reproducible example. However, my real data has clusters and strata, and I'm unsure how to add these to my simple example data

Comment: Even after making the assummption that you expected us to execute `library(survey)` ... with the current code, the first error is "object 'brfss' not found
"

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks!  Sorry, i'm a newb. I added library(survey) and put the correct surveydesign object into the reproducible code, so it no longer throws an error.  Sorry!

Comment: NEVER use `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`. Just use `data.frame`. Use factor for categorical variables. But correcting all those errors of commission and omission did not solve the problem, perhaps because in the end I did not understand the goals.

Comment: @abra could you clarify what numbers you're trying to compare here?  `svychisq()` usually requires `~var1+var2` where `var1` distinguishes the two groups and `var2` contains the distribution you'd like to test?

Answer (score 0):

The help page for `svychisq` says

> At the moment, svychisq works only for 2-dimensional tables.

If it did work for one-way tables (which it doesn't) the syntax you have would be correct.